# Why do site analytics counts not tally?

Tags: support, site-statistics

I just got access to the "[Site Analytics](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics)" privilege, that allows one to look at activity charts for the RPG SE site. The first chart shows the number of posts each day, here for example for last week:

[image]

I would have expected that the total number of posts each day is the sum of the number of questions and answers, the two individual types of posts. However, looking at the chart, this is clearly not the case: for example, on June 29, there were no questions posted, so "all posts" would need to be identical to "answers" on that day, and instead it is larger.

Can someone explain where the difference is from? Is there another, hidden type of post? Is there some time delay effect? Or is there some bug?

(P.S. I am hoping I am not violating the site analytics recommendations on not sharing data here, as I think it is easy enough to see how many questions or answers were posted on a single day, even without it -- you can use the data explorer, or even just tally it up manually for a few days).

Comment: That's perplexing!

Comment: (re: P.S. this is totally fine to share. Honestly, I can't think of anywhere I've bumped up against something someone posted that felt like it might not be sensible to share, but certainly the *existence* of tallies of posts (and their plotting) can't be anywhere near that line.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Because the plot isn't zero'd sensibly

On the 29th of june there weren't 0 posts, there was 5. The same on the 26 and 30th. For whatever reason the plotter put the y-zero at 5, that's why the data looks off.

You can hover over each data point to get the actual value, which is particularly useful as the x-axis markings and the actual days aren't aligned either.